# Style is not applied properly in wpf

Tags: wpf, slider, styles

In my application I have two pages which has the back and forth navigation behavior.

In my first page I have a slider which look like this:

[image]

To get the slider with blue fill i am using the following snippet in its style.

```
<Track Grid.Row="1"
       Name="PART_Track">
    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
        <RepeatButton Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge"
                      Background="Gray" />
    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        <RepeatButton Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge"
                      Background="#4591b1" />
    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton></Track>
```

But the fill is not working in the following scenario.

"Navigate to second page and then come to the first page" . Now i am getting my slider without any blue fill:

[image]

I suspect the style has been overridden. How to get rid of this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the second page does not have the style resource. Check if the second page has the same resources collection as the first one. An if yes please share more code.

Comment: You can use Snoop and investigate the visual tree item including the Styles applied.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed once i wrote separate style for repeat button.

```
 <Style x:Key="IncreaseSliderButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Background="#4591b1"  />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then we need to apply that to slider template

```
  <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton
                                    Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge"
                                    Style="{StaticResource IncreaseSliderButtonStyle}" />
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
```